# Как сделать переход к определенному файлу xml разметки через viewpager который расположен на одном и том же activity?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Cтолкнулся с такой проблемой по незнанию или потому что на придумал не сбыточных идей в своей голове (надеюсь она все такие реализуемая). Есть длинный код всего одной активити в которую я запихнул миллион файлов xml разметки сделав из этого всего подобие учебника по геометрии. И хотелось бы сделать так чтобы со страницы содержания можно было переходить к интересующей пользователя теме
Вот код программы и скрины:

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.diplom0_1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager2 pager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentStateAdapter pageAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);


    }
}
```

MyAdapter:

```
package com.example.diplom0_1;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return(PageFragment.newInstance(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 40;
    }
}
```

PageFragment (основная куча в которую свалены все файлы xml):

```
package com.example.diplom0_1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    private int pageNumber;
    private Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6;
    private Button btnS1, btnS2, btnS3, btnS4;

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle args=new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", page);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PageFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;

    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View result27=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page26, container, false);
        View result26=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page25, container, false);
        View result25=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page24, container, false);
        View result24=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page23, container, false);
        View result23=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page22, container, false);
        View result22=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page21, container, false);
        View result21=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page20, container, false);
        View result20=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page19, container, false);
        View result19=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page18, container, false);
        View result18=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page17, container, false);
        View result17=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page16, container, false);
        View result16=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page15, container, false);
        View result15=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page14, container, false);
        View result14=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page13, container, false);
        View result13=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page12, container, false);
        View result12=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page11, container, false);
        View result11=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page10, container, false);
        View result10=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page9, container, false);
        View result9=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page8, container, false);
        View result8=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page7, container, false);
        View result7=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page6, container, false);
        View result6=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page5, container, false);
        View result5=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page4, container, false);
        View result4=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page3, container, false);
        View result3=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page2, container, false);
        View result2=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, container, false);
        View result1=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
        View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);

        if (pageNumber == 0) {
            ImageView pageHeader = result1.findViewById(R.id.displayImage);
            return result1;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 1){
            ScrollView pageHeader = result2.findViewById(R.id.Soderjanie);
            Button btnS1 = result2.findViewById(R.id.btnS1);
            btnS1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });
            return result2;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 2){
            ImageView pageHeader = result3.findViewById(R.id.displayImage2);
            return result3;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 3){
            ImageView pageHeader = result4.findViewById(R.id.displayImage3);
            return result4;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 4){
            ImageView pageHeader = result5.findViewById(R.id.displayImage4);
            return result5;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 5){
            ImageView pageHeader = result6.findViewById(R.id.displayImage5);
            return result6;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 6){
            ImageView pageHeader = result7.findViewById(R.id.displayImage6);
            return result7;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 7){
            ImageView pageHeader = result8.findViewById(R.id.displayImage7);
            return result8;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 8){
            ImageView pageHeader = result9.findViewById(R.id.displayImage8);
            return result9;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 9){
            ImageView pageHeader = result10.findViewById(R.id.displayImage9);
            return result10;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 10){
            ImageView pageHeader = result11.findViewById(R.id.displayImage10);
            return result11;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 11){
            ImageView pageHeader = result12.findViewById(R.id.displayImage11);
            return result12;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 12){
            ImageView pageHeader = result13.findViewById(R.id.displayImage12);
            return result13;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 13){
            ImageView pageHeader = result14.findViewById(R.id.displayImage13);
            return result14;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 14){
            ImageView pageHeader = result15.findViewById(R.id.displayImage14);
            return result15;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 15){
            ImageView pageHeader = result16.findViewById(R.id.displayImage15);
            return result16;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 16){
            ImageView pageHeader = result17.findViewById(R.id.displayImage16);
            return result17;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 17){
            ImageView pageHeader = result18.findViewById(R.id.displayImage17);
            return result18;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 18){
            ImageView pageHeader = result19.findViewById(R.id.displayImage18);
            return result19;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 19){
            ImageView pageHeader = result20.findViewById(R.id.displayImage19);
            return result20;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 20){
            ImageView pageHeader = result21.findViewById(R.id.displayImage20);
            return result21;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 21){
            ImageView pageHeader = result22.findViewById(R.id.displayImage21);
            return result22;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 22){
            ImageView pageHeader = result23.findViewById(R.id.displayImage22);
            return result23;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 23){
            ImageView pageHeader = result24.findViewById(R.id.displayImage23);
            return result24;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 24){
            ImageView pageHeader = result25.findViewById(R.id.displayImage24);
            return result25;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 25){
            ImageView pageHeader = result26.findViewById(R.id.displayImage25);
            return result26;
        }
        else if (pageNumber == 26){
            ScrollView pageHeader = result27.findViewById(R.id.scroll);
            Button btn1 = result27.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            ImageView img1 = result27.findViewById(R.id.image_otv1);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            Button btn2 = result27.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
            ImageView img2 = result27.findViewById(R.id.image_otv2);
            btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            Button btn3 = result27.findViewById(R.id.btn3);
            ImageView img3 = result27.findViewById(R.id.image_otv3);
            btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    img3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            Button btn4 = result27.findViewById(R.id.btn4);
            ImageView img4 = result27.findViewById(R.id.image_otv4);
            btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    img4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            Button btn5 = result27.findViewById(R.id.btn5);
            ImageView img5 = result27.findViewById(R.id.image_otv5);
            btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    img5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            Button btn6 = result27.findViewById(R.id.btn6);
            ImageView img6 = result27.findViewById(R.id.image_otv6);
            btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    img6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            return result27;
        }
        else{
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

И сам файл xml из которого я хочу сделать содержание:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Soderjanie"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="40dp"
                android:text="Содержание"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnS1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                app:strokeColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button16"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button17"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button18"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Заранее спасибо за потраченное время, и приношу свои искренние извинения за свою глупость.

Answer (score 0):

Для перехода на конкретную позицию используйте метод [`setCurrentItem`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setCurrentItem(int)):

```java
pager.setCurrentItem(20);
```

Если хотите выполнить переход без анимации, то передайте вторым аргументом [`smoothScroll`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setCurrentItem(int,boolean)) значение `false`:

```java
pager.setCurrentItem(20, false);
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, а где это нужно прописать? Для события нажатия на кнопку?

Comment: Например, если вы хотите выполнить это действие по кнопке, то задайте слушатель для этой кнопки: `button.setOnClickListener(v -> pager.setCurrentItem(20));`

Comment: А вот переменная pager это что должно быть?

Comment: Это pager из вашего кода: `ViewPager2 pager = findViewById(R.id.pager);`

Comment: Получается код для кнопки надо прописать в активити MainActivity или можно в PageFragment?

Comment: Где у вас будет содержание, там и добавляйте. Из приведенного в вопросе кода не совсем ясно, по какой кнопке и куда вы хотели бы переходить. Названия лэйаутов не указаны, поэтому я не могу понять, где они у вас используются в коде. В вопросе слишком много лишнего кода, попробуйте сделать [mre], который демонстрирует вашу проблему.